# Fetching limited data from sql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Actually i want to collect data from sql using php while command which is like:

```
while ($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($dat)){//code here}
```

But when i run it, it sends all the records in sql. I just want to display the limited records. How to do that. Even one more question with this can i split all the records into various pages?

Comment: "milted"? What's your query; you could use the where clause to exclude? Pagination could probably be done through the limit and offset clauses, see http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp . TIL that milted has something to do with fish and reproductive glands...

Comment: i would suggest to improve the mysql query to fetch limited data. instead of doing the same in php.

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to do, but you also should really consider using PDO or mysqli instead

Comment: *Milted*? or limited? You can use `LIMIT`. `Your query LIMIT *number you want*`. And I think you are referring to pagination to split the records?

Comment: @Luke So initially i need to make a script which will create the automatic pagination limit for sql query. and then i need to fetch it? Is it right?

Comment: Well, you'd probably have a page number variable in the URL ($_GET[], perhaps). If you wanted to display 10 per page, it'd be something along the lines of `"... LIMIT 10 OFFSET " . (($page - 1) * 10) . ";"`. Again, what's your query? Where is that?

Comment: Can you update your post and give us your query?

Comment: @Luke Thats what is my query
'SELECT * FROM Devices2 ORDER BY name ASC'

Comment: Okay, so I think we've answered your questions. Do you want to try and code something, then seek clarification? Remember to update your first post with your next attempt! :)

Comment: @Luke yep my doubt is clear but i am not getting the concept for pagination.

Comment: Okay, no problem. What isn't clear? Specific questions please, otherwise I write lengthy explanations that are just shooting in the dark :(

Comment: @Luke I have got the idea to get the limited post, but how to apply it to pagination. Means for that i every time need to code and send a new query.

Comment: Well, where do you actually build and run that query? How do you navigate between pages? What URL are we hitting? Show a bit more of your code, please, so that I can see where to put the various elements of our solution :)

Comment: Well it's the query for main index.php and it takes out all the data in form of posts. and i want to display the next post on the same page. That's wht my query fetches.
` echo "<figure><div style='text-align:center;'><img class='prev' src='" . $res[$img] . "'/></div><figcaption><a href='http://mobodroid.net/show.php?q=".  $res[$name] . "'><h3>" . $res[$name] . "</h3></a><img width='80px' height='40px' src='". $comimg ."'/><a class='mor' href='http://mobodroid.net/show.php?q=".  $res[$name] . "'>View Details</a></figcaption></figure>"; `

Comment: soory i dont have idea about putting the code in comments. i am trying with the following but it's not working in my case @Luke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Note:

- You can use LIMIT to limit the number of rows your query has to get.
- And you are referring to pagination to split the records into pages.
- I'll be using `mysqli_*` instead of deprecated `mysql_*`
- I've put some explanations inside
- Replace necessary table name, column name, and connection variable.

You can begin with this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Devices2 ORDER BY name");

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result); /* COUNT THE TOTAL ROW */

$rowsperpage = 20; /* NUMBER OF ROW PER PAGE */
$totalpages = ceil($count / $rowsperpage);

if (isset($_GET['currentpage']) && is_numeric($_GET['currentpage'])) {
      $currentpage = (int) $_GET['currentpage'];
} else {
     $currentpage = 1;
} 

if ($currentpage > $totalpages) {
   $currentpage = $totalpages;
} 
if ($currentpage < 1) {
   $currentpage = 1;
} 

$offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage;

  ?>
    <table><!-- START OF TABLE OF RECORDS -->
  <?php

/* START OF SHOWING THE RECORD */
if($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT name FROM Devices2 ORDER BY name LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage")){

  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($name);
  while($stmt->fetch()){

    ?>
      <tr>
         <td><?php echo $name; ?></td><!-- ROW OF RECORD -->
      </tr>
    <?php

  } /* END OF WHILE LOOP */

  $stmt->close();

} /* END OF PREPARED STATEMENT */

if($count == 0){ /* IF NO RECORD FOUND */
  ?>
    </table>
    <h1>No record found</h1>
  <?php
}

else { /* ELSE, START THE PAGINATION LINK */

  echo '<tr height="30px;" valign="bottom"><td>';

  /* THIS IS THE SECOND TABLE FOR THE PAGINATION LINK */
  echo "<table style='border-collapse:separate; border-spacing:3px;'><tr>";


  /******  build the pagination links ******/
  $range = 2;

  if ($currentpage > 1) {
    $prevpage = $currentpage - 1;
    echo "<td style='width:70px; background-color:fff; border:solid #08c 1px; font-size:14px;' align='center'> <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$prevpage' style='background-color:fff;'>Previous</a> </td>";
  } 


  for ($x = ($currentpage - $range); $x < (($currentpage + $range) + 1); $x++) {

    if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {
      if ($x == $currentpage) {    
        echo "<td style='width:20px; background-color:fff; font-size:14px; border:solid #ccc 2px;' align='center'> <font color='#ccc'><b>$x</b></font> </td>";
      } else {
         echo "<td style='width:20px; background-color:fff; font-size:14px; border:solid #08c 1px;' align='center'> <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?currentpage=$x' style='background-color:fff;'>$x</a> </td>";
      } 
    } 
  }                  

  if ($currentpage != $totalpages) {
    $nextpage = $currentpage + 1;
    echo "<td style='width:70px; background-color:fff; font-size:14px; border:solid #08c 1px;' align='center'> <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?&currentpage=$nextpage' style='background-color:fff;'>Next</a> </td>";

  } // end if
  /****** end build pagination links ******/

  echo "</tr></table></td></tr>";

} /* END OF ELSE IF COUNT 0 */

?>
  </table>
```

Comment: @sgtBOSE Yeah. For someone. :)

Answer (score 6):

Add `limit` to query. [LIMIT](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx)

```
select * from your_table limit 10
```

Or add a `count` for the loop -

```
$count = 1;
while ($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($dat)){
    if($count > 10) {
        break;
    }
    // rest of the code

    $count++:
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use sql's limit feature.
For Ex: If you want to fetch say 10 records then your query should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 0,10;
```

Where '0' is start valueand '10' is number of records in above query.

Answer (score 1):

Use MYSQL LIMIT clause for this.